# How to introduce my project to my unit test project in the c++ qt program

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qttest

I'm pretty new in programming. I have a small project that I want to add a unit test to it. I add a new auto test project as new subprojet to my main project but I don't know how should I introduce and include my classes of another source subproject to unit test.
I added include sentence of one of my classes but I got some error:

[image]

I added

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../TraceFileSource
include( ../TraceFileSource/TraceFileSource.pro )
```

to TraceFileTest.pro but it still dosen't work. I review this answer [Qt creator: c++: undefined reference to Class::Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917677/qt-creator-c-undefined-reference-to-classfunction) but it dosen't clear for me.Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The error you get is because you forget to *link* with one or more object files or libraries. It has nothing to do with including header files.

Comment: And please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Both code and errors can be copy-pasted as text.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your guide, Whitch library should I add?

Comment: The test needs to be built with the source or object files that contains the `Communication` member function definitions (implementations).

Comment: Yes but I got this error whenever I define an object from Communication class.

Comment: Yes, but you get the error because you don't build with the file where the `Communication` constructor is defined. In which source file is `Communication::Communication` defined (implemented)? How do you build your test?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I build the test separately

Comment: You can still build the tests separately, but the test-project or build *must* include all source needed, which includes the ones you want to test.